# Update div rendering after state change

Tags: reactjs

Newbie reactjs user here.

I have a reactjs element `<PlayStopBtn/>` that should basically just toggle displaying START or STOP on each click. My react element looks like this:

```
var PlayStopBtn = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: null};
    },
   onClick: function(event) {
       if(this.state.data == "running")
           this.setState({data: "stopped"});
       else
           this.setState({data: "running"});
   },
   render: function()
   {
       return (<div>{this.state.data == "running" ? "START" : "STOP"}</div>);
   }
});
```

However, when the element renders, it displays STOP and clicking on the element doesn't do anything. Am I doing something wrong or do I have to tell reactjs to rerender the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing setting the onClick handler

```
<div onClick={this.onClick}>{this.state.data == "running" ? "START" : "STOP"}</div>
```

Comment: whoops, thanks. Just found out myself shortly before reading your response